# how to query a column name 'date' in hive?

Tags: hive

Date is a reserved word in hive, but I have a table with column name 'date'. Every time I do "select date from mytable", it gives me an error.

Is there any way to query this column?

Comment: i gues you can use column name within backtick operators

Comment: just tried it but did not work.

Comment: What about using alias: select mytable.date from mytable; ?

Comment: And please, use one question as "SO question" because it'll be messy otherwise

Comment: I tried it too but Hive gives error message. I put the three questions because answering one will give me the answer to the main question(Title).

Answer (score 7):

(backward apostrophe)`date`  (backward apostrophe) -  works well

```
SELECT HD1.holidaydate as holiday_date, HD1.hub_id as holiday_hub_id, to_date(HD2.`date`), HD2.dateno as holiday_dateno
FROM table1 HD1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 HD2 ON HD1.holidaydate = to_date(HD2.`date`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using back-ticks worked for me!

e.g.
`` `date` DATE ``

Answer (score -1):

I used "date" or 'date' -one or the other, and it worked. I just need to put the reserved word between quotes ''
Example...

Select 'date' from mytable;

:)